# I am not able to freely position the button in python's tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, geometry, init

I'm making a hold'em game, and I'm trying to create an in-game start login screen. I'm trying to center the name in a 1280*720 frame, but it's always at the top. Is there any way to solve it?

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except:
    import tkinter as tk

class HoldemApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.geometry("1280x720")
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self.geometry("1280x720")
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        label=tk.Label(self, text= "텍사스 홀덤에 오신것을 환영합니다.")
        start=tk.Button(self, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(LoginPage), text="시작")
        label.place(x=50, y=50)
        start.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor="center")
        label.pack()
        start.pack()

class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)     
        player=tk.Entry(self, text="플레이어 수를 입력하시오")
        cash=tk.Entry(self, text="각 플레이어가 사용할 캐시를 입력하시오.")
        player.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.45, anchor="center")
        cash.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor="center")
        player.pack()
        cash.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = HoldemApp()
    app.title("TEXAS HOLD 'EM")
    app.geometry("1280x720+100+100")
    app.resizable(False, False)
    app.mainloop()
```

I've tried placing geometry("1280x720+100+100") in various places, but there is no response and only an error occurs.

Comment: You shouldn't use both `place` and `pack`. Chose one or the other, but using `place` will likely make it easier to center widgets in the parent window.

Comment: @JRiggles *You shouldn't use both place and pack.* -- Why not? I use `place` almost always as an addition to a geometry manager.

Comment: @Thingamabobs OP uses `place` and `pack` on same widget.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Yeah, I'm not saying you can't / shouldn't use both in the same App. Sorry it that was unclear

Comment: @acw1668 I did not pay attention to the question yet, but this would also be fine if you want to *switch* the geometry manager. If that isn't intended then the wording would still suggest that they are not able to work together like `grid` and `pack`

Comment: @Thingamabobs 
I tried uninstalling the pack and running it, but nothing comes up. If geometry is used late, won't the place in the class be expressed?

Comment: @하루시카 I really don't understand what you are trying to do and therefor not able to help. If you have difficulties to express yourself in English try to work with google translator and post an image with what you get and draw onto that image what you would like to achieve. In addition, if you get an error post the full traceback in your question.

Comment: Remove those *not necessary `.pack()`* and change `self._frame.pack()` to `self._frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)` inside `switch_frame()`.

Comment: The point about `place` and `pack` is that only one will work at a time for a given widget. If you do `label.place(...)` and then almost immediately call `label.pack(...)`, then the call to `place` will have no effect.

Comment: @acw1668 It was solved thanks to you.